# Setting up domain name redirection on Mac OSX for all! domains

Tags: macos, redirect, dns, access-point

im trying to setup a redirection towards an app that im writing in Java. This app opens a port 8443 on my laptop (which is a MacOS 10.10 Yosemite) and offers a HTTPS service.

The big plan is to have another device connecting to an access point that im setting up on my laptop and when it connects to any ip/domain on 443 this traffic is redirected to my local machine on port 8443.

1. I need to redirect traffic that im getting on 443 to 8443. I kinda might have gotten a solution for this using the following guide: http://www.abetobing.com/node/81, and changed the rule to `rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8443`
   But this rule only works locally if im right about that. So only traffic coming from my own laptop is redirected. if im trying to open `https://192.168.178.25/` on another machine it doesn't work, but `https://192.168.178.25:8443/` does.
2. Additionally i also was able to change a domain via the /etc/hosts file. That only works for local connections and for single domains if im right. So the second step would be to redirect ALL possible domain names to my ip. I think this should be possible with kinda of a proxy service, but since i am new to this topic I haven't found a solution that is working for me.
3. At the moment I am using 2 Wifi devices and the MacOS Internet share. My USB wifi card is connected to a router and internet. My internal wifi card opens an access point (it says hotspot) and offers the internet connection of the other device. This is annoying, since the USB wifi connection always has to work, otherwise MacOS will shut down the access point. The best solution would be a software opening a reliable access point with the internal wifi card (haven't had any success with the Mac OS ad-hoc network)

I would be so glad if someone would be able to help me out with any of the 3 single parts. Thank you already :)